# How can I execute tpm2_nvread in the initramfs image created by dracut for centOS 7?

Tags: centos, initramfs, dracut, tpm

I want to load unlock my LUKS partition (root file system) at boot time using a TPM 2.0.

I've had no success using a `keyscript=/path/to/script`  in my `/etc/crypttab` file, however I made progress using methods I found [here](https://www.gaztronics.net/howtos/luks.php).

I am using dracut to build initial ram fs images.

So in `/usr/lib/dracut/modules.d/90crypt`, I have made modifications to several files (according to the guide I linked):

module-setup.sh

```
# gives me access to these binaries at boot time in initramfs
function install() {
    # existing code
    # ...
    inst /sbin/tpm2_nvread
    inst /bin/tail
    inst /bin/perl
    inst /sbin/resourcemgr
}
```

cryptroot-ask.sh

```
resourcemgr &
# yum is only at tpm2-tools 1.1.0, so I can't read keys to a file
# this is my solution to grab from tpm, and convert the spaced out hex to binary
function gettpmkeyfile() {
    key=`tpm2_nvread -x 0x1500001 -a 0x40000001 -s 32 -o 0 | tail -n 1`
    key=${key//[[:blank:]]/}
    key=`echo $key | /bin/perl -ne 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/print chr hex $1/gie'`
    printf $key
}
gettpmkeyfile | cryptsetup luksOpen $device $luksname --key-file=-
```

/etc/dracut.conf

```
omit_dracutmodules+="systemd"
add_dracutmodules+="crypt"
```

i know the binaries are loaded properly, and I've added the keys from the TPM with `luksAddKey`, and I've tested my function on the command line in a shell after booting with a passphrase.

The problem I have is that the `tpm2_nvread` is throwing an error about the resource manager failing to initialize (error `0x1`).

I noticed however that in a normal bootup, the resource manager fails here too, but doesn't prevent me from using the `tpm2-tools` commands.

I've tried upgrading to the latest kernel from elrepo (4.something), and I've added kernel drievrs with dracut like so:

```
dracut --add-drivers tpm_crb --force
```

This doesn't seem to help.

Any advice on how I can get `tpm2_nvread` to work in the initrd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution!

I added `/sbin/strace` to my installed binaries in `module-setup.sh` so i could manually inspect the `tpm2_nvread` command in the dracut shell. Turns out the error was that my network was unreachable.

The tpm2 commands uses `libtcti` to communicate with the tpm, which uses a socket at `127.0.0.1:2323`.

Now, as far as why the loopback was down, I'm not sure. My guess is either `90crypt` in dracut runs before networking is available, or something to do with the fact that I disabled `systemd`.

So I added `/sbin/ifup` to `module-setup.sh`, and added this to my `cryptroot-ask.sh`:

```
ifup lo inet loopback
sleep 3
```

Not sure if I need the sleep but I put it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add "-T device" to your tpm2_nvread so that it talks directly to /dev/tpm0 without needing to go through the resource manager.